# janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Permanent exception while executing backend operation IndexQuery

Tags: janusgraph

I have trouble in query to janusgraph 
I query 50 same request and the result is:

request count                                         50 (OK=11     KO=39    )

> min response time                                   5391 (OK=5391   KO=5697  )
>   max response time                                   5902 (OK=5902   KO=5883  )
>   mean response time                                  5740 (OK=5642   KO=5768  )
>   std deviation                                         98 (OK=158    KO=42    )
>   response time 50th percentile                       5760 (OK=5580   KO=5761  )
>   response time 75th percentile                       5801 (OK=5773   KO=5801  )
>   response time 95th percentile                       5835 (OK=5870   KO=5828  )
>   response time 99th percentile                       5893 (OK=5896   KO=5864  )
>   mean requests/sec                                  5.556 (OK=1.222  KO=4.333 )
>   ---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
>   t < 800 ms                                             0 (  0%)
>   800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   0 (  0%)
>   t > 1200 ms                                           11 ( 22%)
>   failed                                                39 ( 78%)
>   ---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ## > status.find.is(200), but actually found 500                        39 (100.0%)

I use gatling and dropwizard to test janusGrpah.
I see this error in dropwizard

```
ERROR [2018-09-06 07:16:18,159] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: f0cb664169b00267
! java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
! at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:364)
! at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processNextPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:344)
! at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.release(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:318)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.releaseConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:303)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.releaseConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:239)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.responseCompleted(MainClientExec.java:387)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:168)
! at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
! at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
! ... 1 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while performing request
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:682)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:220)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:192)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.performRequest(RestElasticSearchClient.java:334)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.search(RestElasticSearchClient.java:290)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.search(RestElasticSearchClient.java:60)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.query(ElasticSearchIndex.java:1105)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction.queryStream(IndexTransaction.java:108)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$6.call(BackendTransaction.java:417)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$6.call(BackendTransaction.java:414)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:68)
! ... 103 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Permanent exception while executing backend operation IndexQuery
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:81)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:54)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.executeRead(BackendTransaction.java:470)
! at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.indexQuery(BackendTransaction.java:414)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.IndexSerializer.query(IndexSerializer.java:530)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.SubqueryIterator.<init>(SubqueryIterator.java:66)
! ... 98 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not call index
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.SubqueryIterator.<init>(SubqueryIterator.java:68)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx$3.execute(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1295)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx$3.execute(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1190)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor$LimitAdjustingIterator.getNewIterator(QueryProcessor.java:194)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.LimitAdjustingIterator.hasNext(LimitAdjustingIterator.java:68)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.nextInternal(ResultSetIterator.java:54)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.<init>(ResultSetIterator.java:44)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.iterator(QueryProcessor.java:66)
! at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4.iterator(Iterables.java:578)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.JanusGraphStep.executeGraphCentryQuery(JanusGraphStep.java:156)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.JanusGraphStep.lambda$null$1(JanusGraphStep.java:95)
! at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
! at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.JanusGraphStep.lambda$new$2(JanusGraphStep.java:95)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.GraphStep.processNextStart(GraphStep.java:142)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:50)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.FilterStep.processNextStart(FilterStep.java:37)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.DedupGlobalStep.processNextStart(DedupGlobalStep.java:105)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:50)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MapStep.processNextStart(MapStep.java:36)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:50)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MapStep.processNextStart(MapStep.java:36)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.fill(Traversal.java:179)
! at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.toList(Traversal.java:117)
! at ir.mohaymen.utilities.analytics.libintegration._GremlinKt.mapTo(_Gremlin.kt:7)
! at ir.mohaymen.analytics.janusgraphbenchmark.dao.UserDao.findByFullPMixed(UserDao.kt:176)
! at ir.mohaymen.analytics.janusgraphbenchmark.resources.UserResource.findByPMixed(UserResource.java:187)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:241)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:674)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:69)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I search this error in web but I can't find any helpful post.
can anyone help me?